# %nonassoc causing syntax error

Tags: c, bison, yacc, flex-lexer

for an if and if-else statement grammar I have some grammar.

The following is a simplified excerpt from my code to show how I have the if and if-else statement grammar, so if there are errors unrelated to that grammar then don't worry about it. I assure you there are no compilation errors in the code I am using:

```
%token IF ELSE VOID ID VOID_PARAMS

%nonassoc shift_else
%nonassoc ElSE

%%

Func: VOID ID VOID_PARAMS '{' Stmt '}'
;
If_Stmt: IF '(' L_expr ')' Stmt
;
Stmt: If_Stmt shift_else
;
| If_Stmt ELSE Stmt
;
| ';'
| ...
;

L_expr: ...
;
```

It has been working just fine for a while, but now it is finding errors when it reaches the end of a function. For example:

```
void foo(void) {
    if (1 > 5)
        ;
}
```

gives this output ( using yyerror() ):

```
Found unexpected token: '}' on line 4
```

Any suggestions as to why this could be happening? And what can I do to fix this?

Comment: While it's great that you've given us a reduced piece of the code, we can't independently test this out. If you post a minimal, self-contained example that lets us reproduce the issue, we can try things out on our own systems.

Comment: @templatetypedef I can attempt to do this, though before I do, can any of the code associated with each grammar rule effect this? I have some type checking and other stuff going on fore these rules, which would make it basically impossible to give complete code. If I only need the grammar part then it is more reasonable.

Comment: What's a shift_else?

Comment: @immibis Im not sure what you mean, its a placeholder for the empty string I guess, used to resolve the trailing else shift/reduce conflict

Comment: @JDOdle Well, after `if(1 > 5) ;` your parser is expecting either an ELSE, or a shift_else. There clearly isn't an ELSE there. Is there a shift_else there?

Comment: @immibis by defining `shift_else` as `nonassoc` it is assumed to be the empty string right? I thought this was a typical way of resolving the trailing else problem

Comment: @JDOdle You defined ELSE as nonassoc; is it assumed to be the empty string?

Comment: The rules `Stmt: If_Stmt shift_else
;
| If_Stmt ELSE Stmt
;
| ';'
| ...
;` are not legal. It is impossible to help you if you don't post a legal, usable extract of your grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading `if(1 > 5) ;` the parser is expecting an `ELSE` or a `shift_else`.

Presumably there's not an `ELSE` there, since it doesn't appear in the source code.

Unless your lexer conjures a `shift_else` out of thin air, the next token will be a `}`, which is not an `ELSE` or `shift_else`, hence the error.

Comment: `ELSE` is also defined as a `token` thus it would not be the empty string, at least this was my logic. So if `shift_else` is not assumed to be the empty string then what is it? and is there a way to define something as the empty string to resolve the trailing else conflict?

Comment: @JDOdle: I think you're looking for the `%prec` declaration. Read the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Contextual-Precedence)

Comment: @JDOdle `shift_else: ;`?